# Parse.com starter project gives Cannot invoke 'subscribeToChannelInBackground' compiler error on xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, compiler-errors, xcode6.3

If I simply download the starter project, open it in xcode 6.3, update the setApplicationID line and run it, as it says to on the Quickstart screens, i get the error

> Cannot invoke 'subscribeToChannelInBackground' with an argument list
>   of type '(String, block: (Bool, NSError!) -> Void)'

in AppDelegate.swift.

Is there a problem with the latest version of Swift or/and Xcode or have I missed something?

Comment: This is something about swift 1.2
The optionals changed.. 
I think the error is optional (NSError?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RaVeN said, NSError has been changed in Swift 1.2 to be optional.  Therefore, go to where the error is happening, the subscribeToChannelInBackground.

Change this:

```
        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("", block: { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!)
```

To this:

```
        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("", block: { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?)
```

You should be able to compile now without problem.